# Accessing a custom Metal library from another project

Tags: swift, xcode, metal

I am looking to create my own Metal library target in Xcode. The `makeLibrary(filepath:)` described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice/1433416-makelibrary) requires a file with the .metallib extension. Do I have to create the .metallib file manually using each of the metal files in the Metal library target as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/libraries/building_a_library_with_metal_s_command-line_tools) and load it at runtime? Or can I embed it somehow in my app to allow the shaders to be compiled at compile time? The first strategy seems inefficient, and there must be some use for the target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find a better way to tell Xcode to embed the `metallib` into my other target (in my case a framework), so I set up a custom build phase in my framework target to copy the library like this:

[image]

I also added the Metal library target as a dependency to my framework target to ensure that it's always built first.

Comment: This worked for my framework. With another project, the build script was not needed and simply adding the library as a dependency worked (i.e. building the Metal library target) since its output directory matched the `${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}`. But I suppose if I need my shaders to be compiled at compile time I'd need to store them in my project.

Comment: Well, the `metallib` contains compiled shaders, so having them in an extra target should have the same effect.